# PowerShell get out result from a function

Tags: powershell

I have the following code that I'm trying to return the string `Good` as an out parameter from `FooFunc`.

How can I do that?

```
function FooFunc($a, [ref]$result){
    if (4 -gt 1) {
        $result = "Good"
        return $true
    } else {
        $result = "Bad"
        return $false
    }
}


try
{
    FooFunc "Bar" ([ref]$result)
    Write-Host $result
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

**EDIT** I don't want to return the answer with `return`, I need it as `ref` or out `parameters`

Comment: It would help if you provided the actual error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Function Foo{
  if(4 -gt 1)
  {
     return "Good"
  }
  else
  {
     return "Bad"
  }
}

try{
  $result = Foo
  Write-Output $result
}
catch{
   Write-Output "Some message"
}
```

Comment: I need the return for something else, I'm trying to return it as a 'ref' or 'out' params

Answer (score 0):

[ref] is for passing variable into a function so it needs to exist in your current scope which is why you are getting the error. I think you are misunderstanding the usage. Try this:

```
function FooFunc([ref]$result){
    if (4 -gt 1) {
        $result = 'good' + $result.value
        $result        
    } else {
        $result = "Bad"
        return $false
    }
}

try
{
    $result = 'badval'
    FooFunc ([ref]$result) 
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

If you pipe the function to get-member you will see it returns ref and the output is using the variable you are passing in.

Answer (score 0):

Applying [`[ref]`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113255) to a parameter will result in a `PSReference` object being passed to the function.

In the case of `function FooFunc($a, [ref]$result)`, using `$result = "Good"` will change the local `$result` variable in the function from a `PSReference` to a `string`, but will have no effect on the variable the caller passed in. To modify the outer variable, you would want to set `$result.Value = "Good"`.

And as [Noah Sparks mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26219766/2495), on the caller side you also need to declare the variable before using it as argument.

```powershell
function FooFunc( $a, [ref]$result ) {
    if( 4 -gt 1 ) {
        $result.Value = 'Good'  # change the reference value, not the variable
        return $true
    }
    else {
        $result.Value = 'Bad'
        return $false
    }
}


try {
    $result = $null  # declare variable before using it for a reference
    FooFunc 'Bar' ([ref]$result)
    Write-Host $result
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

---

Another option would be to output multiple values from your function:

```powershell
function FooFunc( $a ) {
    if( 4 -gt 1 ) {
        # Output both result and success values
        'Good'
        return $true
    }
    else {
        # This single return is the same as the output and return above
        return 'Bad', $false
    }
}


try {
    $result,$success = FooFunc 'Bar'  # Receive both values
    $success  # Implicitly output success value, as before
    Write-Host $result
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```